# how can we update data in database using entityframework in windows form application.?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

```
    GameSchedulingEntities db = new GameSchedulingEntities();
        Group obj = new Group();
        obj.Name = NametextBox.Text;
        db.Groups.Add(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

No i want to update data in database. how can i do this..I am using Windows Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
        GameSchedulingEntities db = new GameSchedulingEntities();
        Group obj = db.Groups.Find(Id);
        // or Group obj = db.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == NametextBox.Text);
        obj.Name = somethingelse;
        db.SaveChanges();
```